# Building Android-Apps using Jenkins

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, keystore

recently I set up a Jenkins-instance to build mobile-applications, the iOS-build ist working fine, but ATM, I still have problems with the Android-configuration.

Jenkins tells me:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/root/.android/debug.keystore (Permission denied)"
```

My plan was to copy the debug.keystore to a different location where Jenkins can read it, but I'm not sure where I can set the directory (Jenkins, build.xml)?

Thanks and Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Looks like you've created your whole setup with `root` and now try to build it as a different user. That can't be good.

Comment: Well kind of: initially I set up Jenkins using the OS X-installer which was not the best idea, because I had a lot of trouble. Then I switched to the "bare" war-file and started it with java -jar jenkins.war which solved my iOS-build-problems, now I still have the Android-build-problem.

Comment: Since Jenkins can't access that file it means (most probably) that you are not running it as `root` (which is good, in general). So you need to do your whole setup (from beginning to end, for all your projects) with the user Jenkins runs under. That's the surest way not to avoid pesky intractable problems later.